# Simple GUI for a number guessing game

Tags: user-interface, random, tkinter, python-3.4

All right, so I removed the while loop and added the Text field so the answer_txt will have a home.

Now it will work but it always says "Too low" and it won't allow multiple entries.

What am I missing? I am sure this is close.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI Application for Number Guessing Game. """
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    # create widgets
    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text = "Pick a number, 1 - 100: "
              ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.number_ent = Entry(self)
        self.number_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Button(self,
               text = "Submit",
               command = self.get_answer
               ).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.answer_txt = Text(self, width = 40, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.answer_txt.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
    # get answer
    def get_answer(self):
        secret_num = random.randint(1, 100)
        number_ent = 0
        if number_ent < secret_num:
            answer = "Too low, guess again."
        elif number_ent > secret_num:
            answer = "Too high, guess again."
        elif number_ent == secret_num:
            answer = "Congratulations, you guessed right!"
        self.answer_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.answer_txt.insert(0.0, answer)
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Guess")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's better. Reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a while loop in your GUI code like that. The GUI only works when the main loop is allowed to run, and as long as you have your own internal loop, `mainloop` isn't able to run.

GUI programming is different from traditional top-down procedural code. With GUI programming you must set up functions and variables that react to events. Then the user presses submit you need to check one or two things, and then return. As a rule of thumb, any function called in response to a button click or event shouldn't take more than a couple hundred milliseconds to run.